# How can I rebind an element which has unobservable objects in Knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How can I rebind an element which has un-observable objects in Knockout? Let's say i have

```
<ul data-bind="attr:{ }, foreach: items"><li><a rel="external" data-bind="attr: { href: full }" ><img data-bind="attr: { src: thumb, alt: caption }" /></a></li></ul>
```

I can bind this correctly,

```
{
"items":[
                    { "full": "Content\/ImageGallery\/full\/20120502_180612_Josh_Wave_Pint.jpg", "thumb": "content\/imagegallery\/thumb\/20120502_180612_Josh_Wave_Pint.jpg", "caption": "Picture" },
                    {"full":"Content\/ImageGallery\/full\/20130109_173902.jpg","thumb":"content\/imagegallery\/thumb\/20130109_173902.jpg","caption":"Picture"},
                    { "full": "Content\/ImageGallery\/full\/20130107_193641.jpg", "thumb": "content\/imagegallery\/thumb\/20130107_193641.jpg", "caption": "Picture" }
                    ] }
```

But how to rebind this? this does not works,

```
ko.applyBindings(updatedJsonObject, $element[0]);
```

Comment: It sounds like you're pulling in a json object and binding it to your template, then getting a fresh set of json data and wanting to update the displayed html?  knockout is designed to bind the page to a model - I would consider creating a model to hold your data, in this case an observableArray of your full/thumb/caption objects and update that collection instead of trying to rebind.  knockout will take care of the updates without having to rebind

Comment: @JamesThorpe, unfortunately I cannot make it observable

Comment: any particular reason?  that's the usual route you'd go with knockout for items you want to update?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a JS templating engine, instead of KnockoutJS?

Comment: @JamesThorpe, actually the JSON object is coming from some where else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not able to make your array an observableArray, then your main option would be to place that entire structure inside of an observable like:

```
var myStructure = ko.observable();

//update myStructure with new data
myStructure({[...]});
```

Then, you would bind against it like:

```
<div data-bind="with: myStructure">
    <ul data-bind="attr:{ }, foreach: items"><li><a rel="external" data-bind="attr: { href: full }" ><img data-bind="attr: { src: thumb, alt: caption }" /></a></li></ul>
</div>
```

Now, even though the array is not observable, whenever you update `myStructure` (which is observable), the entire section will be re-rendered.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be work. I will more test and let you know if I face an issue.

Comment: Sorry but this also not working in my scenrio. The problem is that the html and JSON is coming from native mobile app. What I am currently doing is that make the html same as it was first time then apply binding again. Please let me know if this option has any disadvantages.

Comment: Not sure that I understand.  Can you put something in jsFiddle?  You generally will not want to applyBindings to the same elements multiple times.  This wil add additional handlers and each element will get updated multiple times.

Comment: Thanks. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LhYUn/ Actually, the application has lot of dependency on native app. That's why I am not using observable.